# Why Intelligencia.UrlRewriter not work with iis6?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Intelligencia.UrlRewriter work with ASP.NET development server but not work in IIS6.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It does work with IIS6
I suspect you are trying to do extensionless rewriting with it - this will not work it iis6

I suggest having a read of this by Scott Guthrie:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you need to install it first when you deploy it on IIS6. Try this installation guide below: http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/installation